# Java String split fails at "\n"

Tags: java, string, split

In a apache camel processor methos I am trying to split a string, which was delivered from an Apache Kafka message broker as JSON. The split routine looks as follows:

```
String[] messageLines = new String[0];

if (messageBody.contains("\\n")) {
    messageLines = messageBody.split("\\n");
} else {
    messageLines = messageBody.split("\n");
}
```

In the debugger, the "messageBody" string looks like this:

```
"deviceName (string:1) -> TEST\nintValue (int:1) -> 123\ndoubleValue (double:1) -> 12.345\nacquisitionStamp (long:1) -> 1592468678231250944\nintArrayValue (int[]:10) -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]"
```

The code runs into the `if (messageBody.contains("\\n")) {...` part, but the `.split("\\n")` returns an array with one entry (the complete messageBody string) only. Same happens is I use `.split("\n")`. What is wrong here?

Comment: Does your text have newlines (`\n`) in them, or literal `\n`?

Comment: `messageBody.split("\\\\n");`

Comment: messageBody contains several instances of literal "\n"

Comment: Then use the second comment `:-)` ... a literal backslash in Java regex is _four_ backslashes

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: "\\\\n" works! thanks. Wanna post a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split()` accepts a regex as argument. In order to match a literal backslash (`\`) in a string, you need 4 backslashes (`\\\\`) in your regex.

The backslash needs to be escaped once for the regex, and then the resulting two backslashes are escaped again for use in the string.

For your example, it would be:

```
messageLines = messageBody.split("\\\\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use StringTokenizer class to split(tokenise)  the string instead of String.split(). 
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "\n") to break the string in the new line.

or 
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "\\n") to break it when there is '\n'

Comment: From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead." So: please don't use `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: I did a test: StringTokenizer(aString, "\\n") splits the example string above at literal "\n" and at character "n" yielding 12 tokens. split("\\\\n") splits exactly where it's supposed to split yielding 5 array items - this is what I expect.